# In my table i don't have a column but i want to use in where condition is it possible or not

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i have two database having same table name but columns name(empno,employee_no) are different so, i want to use single query in both of the table query is given below but i want in a single query.
In where condition i have mention there two different column is it possible or not to write in a single query.

```
select ename 
from emp 
where empno = '1234'---- in 1st databse

select ename 
from emp 
where employee_no = '5678' ---- in 2nd database
```

I want to execute a single query in both database which have two different column of empno and employee_no.
Can anyone please help with same.

Comment: It is unlikely. If both column names appear in the query, even if you write the query in such a way that at runtime only one of them would be used (for example with a `case` expression in the `where` clause, somehow, even assuming that that's possible, or by adding a condition on database name in `where` and hoping that it will be the first one to be evaluated), the query will fail earlier, when it is parsed. The parser requires that ALL columns referenced in the query must exist in the table or tables referenced in the query - even if at execution such columns would not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

One simple method is:

Create `view` in both the database with same name and same alias for empno and employee_no.

```
--In first db
CREATE VIEW MY_TAB_V AS
SELECT EMPNO AS ENO,
...
FROM MY_TAB;


--In second db
CREATE VIEW MY_TAB_V AS
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NO AS ENO,
...
FROM MY_TAB;
```

Now, you will be able to execute following query in both the databases:

```
Select * from MY_TAB_V where ENO=1234;
```

Create a `simple view` so that you will be able to even `update` the tables using that view.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a dynamic SQL statement that queries different columns depending on what is available, by combining `DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML` with the data dictionary.  However, this solution is weird, slow, and buggy, and should be a last resort.  It's usually better to put this level of dynamicism in an application or a PL/SQL block.

```
--Conditional select on EMP depending on which column exists.
--
--Convert XML to regular values.
select extractvalue(xml, '/ROWSET/ROW/ENAME') empname
from
(
    --Convert to XMLType.
    --(This is nontrivial because NULL must be handled oddly.)
    select
        case when xml is null then
            xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?><ROWSET><ROW><ENAME></ENAME></ROW></ROWSET>')
            else xmltype(xml)
        end xml
    from
    (
        --Get dynamic result as XML.
        select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select ename from emp where '||column_name||' = 1234') xml
        from dba_tab_columns
        where owner = user
            and table_name = 'EMP'
            and column_name in ('EMPNO', 'EMPLOYEE_NO')
    )
);
```

Use these commands to test the statement:

```
drop table emp;
create table emp(ename varchar2(100), empno number);
insert into emp values ('asdf', 1234);
commit;

<run the above SELECT>

drop table emp;
create table emp(ename varchar2(100), employee_no number);
insert into emp values ('qwer', 1234);
commit;

<run the above SELECT>
```